# How to make a shape a fixed size, in draw.io?

Tags: draw.io

I have draw.io hosted locally and we are using it to have a visual representation of what pallets are where in our warehouse. The problem is that is that when dragging pallets around you often accidentally resize them, which is a pain. Is there anyway i can disable this or lock the size of the pallets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select a shape and in the right-hand format panel click "edit style":

[image: draw.io format panel]

The style is a set of key/value semicolon separated pairs. Add `resizable=0;` to the style and press OK:

[image]

When you duplicate this shape the style will also be copied. You might also want to create a custom library with the style present.